# Initial Collision Detection in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I recently have run into a problem with a simple collision detection test in my Pygame project.  I am purposely not using the `Sprite` class and some of the built in collision functions provided by Pygame for learning purposes.  The problem I am having is not that the collisions aren't detected.  The problem is that the collisions are lasting longer than they should be.

If you run my code, you will see that the `Obstacle` objects randomly falling down the screen pass through the `Player` object for some time, even after they have disappeared.  `collisions` counts the number of coordinates that the `Obstacle` passes through `Player`, which seems to typically be in-between -17 to -21.  Why is this happening?  Since the boolean `obstacle.exists = False` is stated, shouldn't the  `Obstacle` object be instantly destroyed before it has time to pass through `Player` -17 to -21 intersecting coordinates?  Could this possibly be caused by an fps issue?? 
Basically, what I am trying to figure out is how to get `Obstacle` to be destroyed *instantly* upon collision, so that `collisions` only subtracts once.

Comment: Somehow unrelated but you might want to test your booleans with `if variable` or `if not variable` instead of `== True` or `== False`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Thanks for the info. Ill see if I can clean stuff up!

Comment: Also your tests inside the collision détection are unneeded: `if obstacles.exists == False` just after `obstacles.exists = False`. Same for  `collided`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collision detection is made regardless of the existence of an obstacle. You should add `obstacles.exists` as first test on your collision détection:

```
if (obstacles.exists and 
        obstacles.x < player.x + player.w and
        obstacles.x + obstacles.w > player.x and
        obstacles.y < player.y + player.h and
        obstacles.h + obstacles.y > player.y):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help! This did exactly what I needed. One last thing... Since the `obstacles.exists` is now `False`, it seems that the from that point on,  `obstacles` will not be able to continue spawning unless their `obstacle.exists` is once again `True`?

Comment: Maybe that is where using `if variable or if not variable` comes into play

Comment: @tear728 Not at all, the `if variable` syntax is just removing redundancy in your code. What you want to spawn multiple obstacles can be achieved 1) either reinstantiate a new obstacle (`obstacles = Obstacle(new_x, new_y)` at the end of your collision detection (before the `else` for instance) or at random when you don't have any: `if not obstacles.exists and random.randint(10) == 7: obstacles = Obstacle(new_x, new_y)` or 2) by using a list of obstacles and spawning multiple at once. In this case, the exists attribute will be of no use anymore and removing obstacles from the list will suffice.